# CSS: modifying only one element inside of a class

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Please look at the following image:

My current UI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dlyJ.png

I have one class, `<div class="newsfeed">` which modifies each post that gets created.

The issue I have is that I want to modify the 'edit' and 'delete' glyphicon buttons without affecting the rest of the class. Specifically, I want to move them both to the top right corner of the post.

Now, I know I can create a separate class (or an ID); however, how will the class know I'm referencing the newsfeed class? For example, if I wanted to fixate them to the right, how would they know to stick to the right hand side of the box rather than the page?

All help is massively appreciated. Massive bonus for anybody who can provide me with the CSS required. :)

Thanks all!

Edit - below is all my current code contained inside of my view:

```
   <% if @posts.any? %> 
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div id="post_<%= post.id %>">
      <div class ="newsfeed">
        <div class="well">
          <% if post.user.has_image? %>
            <div class="profile_pic"><%= image_tag post.user.images.first.file(:profile), class: "img-thumbnail", alt: "Cinque Terre", width: "50", height: "50" %></div>
          <% else %>
            <div class ="profile_pic"><%= image_tag "default_user_image.png",class: "img-thumbnail", alt: "Cinque Terre", width: "50", height: "50" %></div>
          <% end %>
        <div class="name_and_time">
          <a href="/users/<%= post.user.id %>/show"><%= post.user.first_name %> <%= post.user.last_name %></a><br>
          <span><%= post.created_at.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M") %></span>
        </div>
        <% if !post.image.exists? %>
          <h2> <%= post.text %> </h2>
        <% else %>
          <h2> <%= link_to post.text, post_path(post) %> </h2>
          <%= link_to post_path(post) do %>
            <p><%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %></p>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <% if @user %>
          <% if current_user.voted_up_on?(post) %>
            <%= link_to "Like", dislike_post_path(post), method: :put %>
          <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Like", like_post_path(post), method: :put %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <%= "#{post.get_upvotes.size} | " %>
        <div class="edit_and_delete_posts">
        <% if post.user == current_user %>
          <%= link_to edit_post_path(post) do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
          <% end %>
          <%= link_to post_path(post), method: :delete do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          <% end %>
        </div>
          <div class='comments_div'>
            <%= render post.comments %>
          </div>
          <% if current_user %>
            <%= form_for [post, post.comments.new ], remote: true do |f| %>
              <%= f.text_area :text, placeholder: 'Add a comment' %>
              <%= f.submit 'Comment' %>
              <% end %>
          <% else%>
            <p>You need to <%= link_to "sign in", new_user_session_path %> to comment</p>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
    No posts have been added!
<% end %>
```

Comment: Post the full HTML of **one** `<div class="newsfeed">`.

Comment: Hey! Done, although do you mind if I ask why it's necessary in answering the primary question? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have posted the CSS. I asked the full HTML (including all child elements) of **one** `<div class="newsfeed">`.

Comment: It is necessary to know the structure in order to decide how to call elements

Comment: How is that? Apologies about the somewhat shoddy formatting -- I'll edit it to make it look neater as soon as possible.

Comment: No, we need the resulting HTML, not the Ruby program. View Source in your browser and select the part you want.

Comment: Never mind; Dre solved the issue with the information provided. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you post the full compiled HTML and the CSS I could show you a working demo, but what you need to add is this:

```
.newsfeed {
    position:relative;
}
.edit_and_delete_posts {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

By adding `position:absolute` to the `.edit_and_delete_posts` div, it's pulled out of the flow, so that it doesn't affect the rest of the elements. You can then set it's `top` and `right` positions; this sets it to the top right of the *closest ancestor element with relative positioning.* Since `.newsfeed` has `position:relative` it's the closest ancestor, and thus `.edit_and_delete_posts` will be positioned *relative* to this.

You can then add additional margin or padding to fine tune it if necessary.